# Count occurrences in a line and push results to a column

Tags: unix, awk

I have a fairly simple issue. In `file1`, I want to count how many `H` exist per line, sum the count, and print the count and row number as two columns at the end of the same or different file.

Input:

```
h1 h2 h3 h4
A  H  H  B
B  H  C  H
A  A  A  H
```

Desired output:

```
h1 h2 h3 h4 count rowid
A  H  H  B      2     1
B  H  C  H      2     2
A  A  A  H      1     3
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{print $0 "count", "rowid"} {print gsub(/H/,"") FS NR}' file1.txt >out.txt
```

Where is my error and what do I change to make it work?

Comment: You shouldn't link to pictures of your input/output, but paste the text in the question itself.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't let new users do that until they get 10 reputation points.

Comment: I mean not paste the picture, but type the text in. Copy paste, so it's copy-pasteable for people who want to test.

Comment: Got it. Will follow it from next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $0, "count", "rowid"; next} 
            {print $0, gsub("H","H"), NR-1}' file | 
  column -t

h1  h2  h3  h4  count  rowid
A   H   H   B   2      1
B   H   C   H   2      2
A   A   A   H   1      3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir! I changed it just a bit to suit my needs. Much appreciated. `awk 'NR==1{print $0 "\t" "count" "\t" "rowid"; next} {print $0 "\t" gsub("H","H") "\t" NR-1}' file1.txt > out.txt`

Comment: instead on the original code set `awk -v OFS='\t' ...`.

Comment: @berge2015, expanding on karakfa's comment, set OFS to tab then use commas in the print statements: `awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==1{print $0, "count", "rowid"; next} {print $0, gsub("H","H"), NR-1}'` -- that looks tidy.